# Why are two menu items with the same CSS acting differently?

Tags: html, css

[link removed]

Menu items within 'projects' are clickable but not in 'about us'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a z-index set on class "div.menu-hover-about"

```
div.menu-hover-about {
display:block;
height:198px;
margin-left:25px;
position:absolute;
width:73px;
z-index:10;
```

taking it out seems to do the trick! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that 'projects' left margin is actually on top of the 'about us' menu.  Try giving the 'about-us' menu a z-index of 1 or more and it should work.

Note: Don't forget to give the 'about-us' menu a position: relative or absolute, otherwise z-index doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just used a little bit of firebug trickery and apparently it has something to do with the z-index of the ul that is revealed when you hover over the "about us" header. if you set the z-index to 10 it works perfectly.